# Publishing a web app to iis 8 express

Tags: iis

I am struggling to deploy a web app to iis 8 express.  I have no problem deploying it to the regular IIS 7.5.  IIS 8 express does not have any GUI so I cannot go into it, create a virtual directory, point to the physical folder where the web app files are.  I have been looking up on internet with zero results.  Any good examples out there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [IIS Express GUI](https://iisexpressgui.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I downloaded and used it (not the most friendly GUI) and the browser still said: cannot see signalr js and other things.  I was hoping iis express 8 will serve up my signalr web app.  I don't have server 2012.

Comment: I am trying to pitch signalr capability for realtime to my organization, but if you cannot even host the app, it is quite bad.